# rails_admin how to make a table name singular

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I am using rails_admin.

My model is:

```
class Info < ActiveRecord::Base
    set_table_name "info" 
end
```

But in rails_admin It shows as **Infos**.
How can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: Add `pluralize_table_names = false` before it too; `migrate` and see if that works for you. :)

Comment: But pluralize_table_names = false is global setting. I would like to set only the Info model singular.

Comment: When added in a `class Info`, it will be meant only for `Info`. Not sure about it though. :|

Comment: I have added it in such way: class Info < ActiveRecord::Base
 pluralize_table_names = false
 set_table_name "info" 
end but it didn't help me. In rails_admin I still see Infos

Comment: It needs to be `self.pluralize_table_names = false`.  Without `self.` it simply creates a local variable that does nothing.

Comment: Yes, @PinnyM is absolutely right. I missed that, sorry. :)

Comment: Thanks for reply, PinnyM, kiddorails. But even **class Info < ActiveRecord::Base self.pluralize_table_names = false set_table_name "info" end** didn't solve my problem (

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but this worked for me (Rails 3):

```
class Info < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = 'info'
end
```